# How to save image using skimage.io.imsave to save in color

Tags: python, image, png

I am trying to save the scalogram image in color instead of the greyscale that I am currently getting with this code:

```
import librosa
import librosa.display

import os
import pywt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import soundfile as sf
  
import numpy as np
from ssqueezepy import cwt
from ssqueezepy.visuals import plot, imshow

# Set the path to the Binary Class dataset
fulldatasetpath = 'G:/AudioFile'

input_file = (r'G:/Audiofile.wav')


[data1, sample_rate1] = sf.read(input_file)
#[sample_rate1, data1] = wav.read(input_file);
duration = len(data1)/sample_rate1

time = np.arange(0, duration, 1/sample_rate1) #time vector

Wx, scales = cwt(data1, 'morlet')

imshow(Wx,  abs=1)
plt.show()

Wx = abs(Wx)

def scale_minmax(X, min=0.0, max=1.0):
    X_std = (X - X.min()) / (X.max() - X.min())
    X_scaled = X_std * (max - min) + min
    return X_scaled

wave1 = np.log(Wx + 1e-9) # add small number to avoid log(0)

# min-max scale to fit inside 8-bit range
img = scale_minmax(Wx, 0, 255).astype(np.uint8)
img = np.flip(img, axis=0)  # put low frequencies at the bottom in image
img = 255-img # invert. make black==more energy
out = 'out.png'
# save as PNG
skimage.io.imsave(out, img)
```

Can you please help me to save the PNG image in color?

Thanks for your time!